# textview get overide by image from gallery

Tags: iphone

I am trying to place text view on image view of particular size, but when i load the image from photo gallery my text view get over written and I am not able to write upon it . I guess, when I create a rectangle frame for bi then image from gallery get override to text view. what should I do?

answer: this is working ocde:

```
- (void)imagePickerController:(UIImagePickerController *)picker 
didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo:(NSDictionary *)info {
    // set image
    emailImage1 = [info objectForKey:UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage];
    //bi.image = [info objectForKey:UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage];

    image = [info objectForKey:UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage];
    bi = [[UIImageView alloc ] initWithImage: image ];
    bi.frame = CGRectMake(20.0f, 100.0f,260.0f, 285.0f);
    [self.view addSubview: bi];
    [self.view bringSubviewToFront:scroll];
    [[picker parentViewController] dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES];
    [picker release];
}

- (void)imagePickerControllerDidCancel:(UIImagePickerController *)picker 
   {
    // release picker
    [[picker parentViewController] dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES];
    [picker release];
}
```

help plz

Answer (score 0, accepted):

syntax was  `[self.view bringSubviewToFront:yourTextView];`

Comment: giving warning "uiview maynot respond to bringsubviewtofront" and its not selecting the image form gallery!!

Answer (score 1):

Hey There, 
There's onyl one line which causes the problem. You add the `bi` as a subview like this:

```
[self.view addSubview: bi ];
```

That's correct. But look at this from the domentation of UIView:

> After being added, this view appears on top of any other subviews.

Try the following instead

```
[self.view insertSubview: bi belowSubview: YourTextView];
```

Replace 'YourTextView' with a pointer to your textview. Than it should work.

Sandro Meier

Comment: i guess whenever the rectangle is created it occupies new position overriding all the views. . . what you think?

Comment: i had made some shuffling with some bunch of code and it gets working.i am editing my code..